# Sql query accept value in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a table called Invoice, in that table there are two columns TotalDue and Total balance. for my requirement i retrieved data such as (
SELECT * FROM Invoice_TBL WHERE IsTableStatus = 1 AND ClientNo = 3 AND TotalBalance > 0 ORDER BY InvoiceNo ASC)
the above query retrieved all the total balance of selected customer.

Now i wanted to do is "Retrieve all the total balances with accept one paid invoice no balance which i have selected"

or

```
SELECT AutoInvoiceNo, InvoiceNo, TotalBalance
FROM Invoice_TBL
WHERE IsTableStatus = 1 AND ClientNo = 3 AND TotalBalance > 0 ;


SELECT AutoInvoiceNo, InvoiceNo, TotalBalance
FROM Invoice_TBL
WHERE IsTableStatus = 1 AND ClientNo = 3 AND AutoInvoiceNo = 5
```

How to merge above 2 query and get one result..

Please help me..
Thanks...

Comment: Your requirement is incomprehensible. Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: same number and same columns..why can't you use Union?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the `where` clauses:

```
SELECT AutoInvoiceNo, InvoiceNo, TotalBalance
FROM Invoice_TBL
WHERE IsTableStatus = 1 AND ClientNo = 3 AND (TotalBalance > 0 OR AutoInvoiceNo = 5)
```

Comment: Thank you. Amir Rahimi Farahani.... working fine i tried using UNION ALL also thaks again.